# I declared a variable of a custom type in a stored procedure but still getting error "must declare scalar variable"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I created a custom  table type

```
Create type dbo.InsertPatient as table
(SSN Int,
 LastUpdated Datetime,
 PatientId varchar(50),
 McdNo varchar(50),
 mcrno varchar(50)
)
GO
```

I tried to declare an input parameter using this type

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_PatientDt_Insert]
(
    @PatientTable InsertPatient READONLY,
    @FacilityID int,
    @IsDeleted bit = 0
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
    DECLARE @Err int

    IF(@IsDeleted = 1)
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM [Patient]
        WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM([Patientid])) = LTRIM(RTRIM(@PatientTable.PatientId))
          AND FacilityID = @FacilityID

        RETURN
    END

    SET @Err = @@Error

    RETURN @Err
END
```

When I try to execute, I get this error

> Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure proc_PatientDt_Insert, Line 18
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@PatientTable".

Comment: If the variable is a table, don't you need to join with it?

Comment: why would that help the problem of it still needing to be declared?

Comment: Because it is not a **scalar** variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is a little misleading, but it's because you're trying to use a Table Varaible as if it was a plain old scalar variable.  Table variables work more or less like tables.  While it's possible the variable will only have one row, it could have 100.  You need to `SELECT` and/or `JOIN` from that variable.  If you only ever expect to have 1 row, or want to take an arbitrary first row and ignore others, you could change

```
LTRIM(RTRIM([Patientid])) = LTRIM(RTRIM(@PatientTable.PatientId)) AND FacilityID=@FacilityID
```

to

```
LTRIM(RTRIM([Patientid])) = LTRIM(RTRIM(SELECT TOP 1 PatientId FROM @PatientTable)) AND FacilityID=@FacilityID
```

But you'd probably be best off doing:

```
DELETE p
FROM Patient p
INNER JOIN @PatientTable p2
ON LTRIM(RTRIM(p.PatientId) =  LTRIM(RTRIM(p2.PatientId)
WHERE p.FacilityId = @FacilityId
```